# PHP Word sends back unreadable file

Tags: php, symfony, phpword, php-7.3

I have a Symfony application running on the web - and PHP Word does a good job.

The same application is running on my localhost but with a higher Symfony version and also a higher PHP version of 7.39.

And PHP Word sends unreadable files. I upgraded to PHP Word from 0.15 to version 0.17, but the problem stays.

I reduced my code - to exclude code mistakes. Now I only have an empty document, but the file is unreadable.

```
    // Creating the new document...
    $phpWord = new PhpWord();

    // Saving the document as OOXML file...
    $objWriter = IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');


    // Create a temporal file in the system
    $fileName = 'Planungsuebersicht_' . $this->getUser() . '.docx';

    $temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $fileName);

    // Write in the temporal filepath
    $objWriter->save($temp_file);
```

[Dropbox-link to a unreadable (blank) .docx-file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kaz7v798a24zs3f/Planungsuebersicht.docx?dl=0)

When you try to open it, you should see the following error-messages in your language:

[image: In the background - you can even see the readable document - I just downloaded from the application running in the web with lower php-version (PHP 7.0)]

It worked now for years - and now it give back unreadable files even when I try to produce a blank page.

Comment: why are you trying to run it on such a new version of php? phpword has had issues in the past with php7 https://www.google.com/search?q=phpword+in+php+7

Comment: I need it for my symfony project. I did not know about this issues. Symfony 4.4 needs 7.2.5. But anyway I can not restrict all my project to this feature. Is there not a workaround?

Comment: I mean I have a huge amount of dependencies in my project all works fine with higher php versions. But not PHP-Word. Is that possible :S ?

Comment: Short answer NO you can't  you need to have same version of php everywhere unless you have a new project with and old php version and use an API to do the work :(

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to make of the above comments about the php version compatibility and referring to old resolved issues with the library... For me everything is working fine with php7.2 and PhpWord 0.17. Including this simple example in the question. So you could give it a go whether using that 7.2.* version , that is possible for you, makes a difference.

Comment: It actually works fine on my machine now. I wonder why the mamp server did not gave error responses. Anyway the symfony local server (build in) - gave me a nice error message - that ZIP Archives are not installed. 
I just reinstalled my php with zip - archives (Homebrew). Because to install this exentions on mac os 10.15 is not so easy anymore. brew update -
brew install php@7.3 -
brew link php@7.3 -
Now it runs even with php 7.3.